# Crash when starting daemon but not when starting normal

Tags: init-file, emacsclient, emacs-daemon

OSX Yosemite 10.10.4, emacs installed via

`brew install emacs-mac`

`GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.4.0, Carbon Version 157 AppKit 1348.17) of 2015-07-20 on Rainers-MacBook-Pro.local`

I want to start emacs as a daemon but I get the following error when starting:

```
02:12:24 ~$ emacs --daemon
Loading /Users/rainerkrug/.emacs.d/emacs.el (source)...
Loading quail/latin-pre...
Loading quail/latin-pre...done


Loading package uniquify...
Configuring package uniquify...
Configuring package uniquify...done
Loading package uniquify...done
Loading package exec-path-from-shell...
Configuring package exec-path-from-shell...
Configuring package exec-path-from-shell...done (0.242s)
Loading package exec-path-from-shell...done (0.245s)
Loading package epa...
Configuring package epa...
Configuring package epa...done
Loading package epa...done
`epa-file' already enabled
Loading package highlight-parentheses...
Configuring package highlight-parentheses...
Configuring package highlight-parentheses...done
Loading package highlight-parentheses...done
Loading package autopair...
Configuring package autopair...
Configuring package autopair...done
Loading package autopair...done
Try library `outorg-export' for automated export to all Org
       backends:
https://github.com/jleechpe/outorg-export
.emacs.d/.cask/24.5.1/elpa/sr-speedbar-20141004.532/sr-speedbar.elc:Warning:
    reference to free variable `helm-alive-p'
Loading package sos...
Loading package sos...done
Loading package dired-details...
Loading package dired-details...done
Loading package pdf-tools...
Loading package pdf-tools...done (0.224s)
Loading package imenu-anywhere...
Loading package imenu-anywhere...done

Backtrace:
0   emacs                               0x00000001000c2a4a emacs_backtrace + 87
1   emacs                               0x00000001000a7e3d terminate_due_to_signal + 97
2   emacs                               0x00000001000c3455 tcsetpgrp_without_stopping + 0
3   emacs                               0x00000001000c28f3 maybe_fatal_sig + 0
4   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00007fff95c1ff1a _sigtramp + 26
5   ???                                 0x0000000000000000 0x0 + 0
6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff98658cfc _dispatch_mach_msg_send + 1690
7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff986585e4 dispatch_mach_send + 326
8   libxpc.dylib                        0x00007fff91d7c3b8 xpc_connection_send_message_with_reply + 114
9   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff94395b6f __80-[CFPrefsSearchListSource generationCountFromListOfSources:count:allowFetching:]_block_invoke_2 + 143
10  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff943c655b _CFPrefsWithDaemonConnection + 331
11  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff94395ac6 __80-[CFPrefsSearchListSource generationCountFromListOfSources:count:allowFetching:]_block_invoke + 150
12  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff943959d2 -[CFPrefsSearchListSource generationCountFromListOfSources:count:allowFetching:] + 258
13  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff94251ea5 -[CFPrefsSearchListSource alreadylocked_copyDictionary] + 133
14  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9424cdba -[CFPrefsSearchListSource alreadylocked_copyValueForKey:] + 42
15  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff943c711c ___CFPreferencesCopyAppValueWithContainer_block_invoke + 60
16  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff94394979 +[CFPrefsSearchListSource withSearchListForIdentifier:container:perform:] + 729
17  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff943c7097 _CFPreferencesCopyAppValueWithContainer + 183
18  emacs                               0x000000010016d069 Fmac_get_preference + 386
19  emacs                               0x0000000100117da9 Ffuncall + 1075
20  emacs                               0x000000010014a8ae exec_byte_code + 2147
21  emacs                               0x00000001001187da funcall_lambda + 750
22  emacs                               0x0000000100117bc9 Ffuncall + 595
23  emacs                               0x000000010014a8ae exec_byte_code + 2147
24  emacs                               0x0000000100114c0b eval_sub + 1688
25  emacs                               0x0000000100115419 Fdefvar + 101
26  emacs                               0x0000000100114a0c eval_sub + 1177
27  emacs                               0x00000001001342d4 readevalloop + 1446
28  emacs                               0x0000000100133045 Fload + 2062
29  emacs                               0x000000010011f713 Frequire + 524
30  emacs                               0x0000000100117d85 Ffuncall + 1039
31  emacs                               0x000000010014a8ae exec_byte_code + 2147
32  emacs                               0x0000000100114c0b eval_sub + 1688
33  emacs                               0x00000001001342d4 readevalloop + 1446
34  emacs                               0x0000000100133045 Fload + 2062
35  emacs                               0x000000010011f713 Frequire + 524
36  emacs                               0x0000000100114c0b eval_sub + 1688
37  emacs                               0x000000010011646f internal_lisp_condition_case + 543
38  emacs                               0x000000010014b6d9 exec_byte_code + 5774
39  emacs                               0x00000001001187da funcall_lambda + 750
40  emacs                               0x0000000100117bc9 Ffuncall + 595
...
Error: server did not start correctly
02:12:41 ~$
```

When using `emacs -Q --daemon` the daemon starts without problems.

Any suggestrions how I can find out what is causing the error, without having to disect my emacs.el file?

Comment: It's going to be faster to bisect your init file. You can't go wrong with `log n` complexity and for an extra boost, start with everything after the last successful message.

Comment: It seems the crash happens within a function named `mac-get-preference`.

Comment: @wasamasa  Did the Bisection and found the offending command - ```(org-mobile-pull)```. I will post on the org mailing list. Thanks.

Comment: @YoungFrog No idea what this function is - how did you find the name?

Comment: @Rainer The backtrace shows a call to `Ffuncall` then `Fmac_get_preference`. The convention is that C functions which are available to lisp are prefixed by F and have underscores instead of dashes, so it means mac-get-preference was called.

Answer (score 4):

Bisecting the emacs.el init file by inserting `(error "Done)` to quit the init file at that location, I was able to quickly find the offending call, in my case `(org-mobile-pull)`.

Comment: Nice, that's a less tedious method than commenting out!

Comment: I can't take credit for this - I found it in another stackexchange question (can't find it at the moment) here if is http://stackoverflow.com/a/25395399